# How to find the percentage in each branch from one array ? In C (Answered)

Tags: c, arrays

(edits at the bottom of the question.)

So for example let's have an array that is filled with some elements for each month in the year. The user inputs first the amount of branches he wants to input data about and as such the program loops itself and stores them in **one** array, we make another function and have it calculate the sum of all the data that was input by the user. Now, what to do, we need to make it show the percentage of each branch as a whole.

```
Input: Please enter the number of branches you'd like to input data about : 2
Branch 1
Enter the data for the month 1 : 123
Enter the data for the month 2 : 123
Enter the data for the month 3 : 123
Enter the data for the month 4 : 123
Enter the data for the month 5 : 123
Enter the data for the month 6 : 123
Enter the data for the month 7 : 123
Enter the data for the month 8 : 123
Enter the data for the month 9 : 123
Enter the data for the month 10 : 123
Enter the data for the month 11 : 123
Enter the data for the month 12 : 123

Branch 2
Enter the data for the month 1 : 123
Enter the data for the month 2 : 123
Enter the data for the month 3 : 123
Enter the data for the month 4 : 123
Enter the data for the month 5 : 123
Enter the data for the month 6 : 123
Enter the data for the month 7 : 123
Enter the data for the month 8 : 123
Enter the data for the month 9 : 123
Enter the data for the month 10 : 123
Enter the data for the month 11 : 123
Enter the data for the month 12 : 123


The sum of all the branches income combined is = 2952.000000 

Required output: Branch 1 has : 50%
 Branch 2 has : 50%
```

(yes this is my first time asking a question here)

(here's the entire code in case it's needed EDIT 2: Thanks to Armali for fixing the old broken code btw)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Data_Of_Branches(int number_of_branches, float arr_brms[number_of_branches][12])
{
  int i;
  int j;
  for (i = 0; i < number_of_branches; i++)
  {
    printf("Branch %d\n", i + 1);
    for (j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
      printf("Enter the data for the month %d: ", j + 1);
      scanf("%f", &arr_brms[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

float sum_of_sales(int number_of_branches ,float arr_brms[number_of_branches][12])
{
  float total_sale = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < number_of_branches; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) total_sale += arr_brms[i][j];
  printf("The sum of all the branches income combined is = %f\n\n", total_sale);
return total_sale;}

void percentage(int number_of_branches, float arr_brms[number_of_branches][12])
{
    int i, j, m = 12;
    float total = sum_of_sales(number_of_branches, arr_brms);
    for (i = 0; i < number_of_branches; i++)
    {
        printf("Branch %d: ", i+1);
        float per, sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) sum += arr_brms[i][j];
        per = (sum / total) * 100.0;
        printf("Percentage = %.2f%%\n", per);
    }
}



int main()
{
  printf(
      "Please enter the number of branches you'd like to input data about: ");
  int number_of_branches = 0;
  scanf("%d", &number_of_branches);
  float arr_brms[number_of_branches][12];
  Data_Of_Branches(number_of_branches, arr_brms);
  printf("Hello. please enter the number of the operation you'd like to do. "
         "(please only enter the number.) \n \n");
  int choice;
    float total_sale;
  while (
    printf(" 1. Enter sales data.\n 2. Add a record for a new branch \n 3. "
           "Delete record of an existing branch \n 4. Calculate total sales \n "
           "5. Calculate percentage share of each branch \n 6. Determine the "
           "month of the peak sales \n 7. Display sales of a specific month \n "
           "8. Display sales of a specific branch \n 0. Done \n"),
    scanf("%d", &choice) > 0
        )
  {
    if (choice == 0) exit(0);
    if (choice == 1) Data_Of_Branches(number_of_branches, arr_brms);
    if (choice == 4) sum_of_sales(number_of_branches, arr_brms);
        if (choice == 5)percentage(number_of_branches, arr_brms);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT : Okay so basically what i need is the way to fix the sum function. since it keeps displaying wrong numbers. and another function to display the percentage of each branch from the sum

EDIT 2: alright so after replacing the old code with the new one that Armali put. i went ahead and started -failing miserably at- adding the percentage function. so if possible is there a way to fix the void percentage function?

EDIT 3: Many thanks to Armali for helping. i updated the code to add said functions in case anyone wants it of course. hope this help **and again thank you Armali**

Comment: When you read in your data in the Data_Of_Branches function for every branch you write your data into the same array arr_month. This means you overwrite the data of earlier branches. Because of that your sum is wrong and you will not be able to calculate the percentage income of every branch

Comment: Honestly, I didn't understand what you need to do ...

Comment: @mlwn
basically i want to make the code be able to show the percentage of  sales in each branch but i can't seem to do that without fixing the Data_Of_Branches function (Which i can't seem to be able to do either so is there a way you could help?

Comment: Note (and consider at least next time) that the question becomes somewhat meaningless if there's only the working code shown; hence it would be better to make an answer post with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> … what i need is the way to fix the sum function. since it keeps displaying wrong numbers.

Of course *it keeps displaying wrong numbers* because it gets incomplete data, as Oli L correctly explained:

> When you read in your data in the Data_Of_Branches function for every branch you write your data into the same array arr_month. This means you overwrite the data of earlier branches. Because of that your sum is wrong and you will not be able to calculate the percentage income of every branch

A solution is to store the data in a two-dimensional array, not only for each month, but also for each branch. Then *the sum function* can loop over both and compute the correct sum.
Besides that, your main loop likely doesn't do what you want; you shouldn't call `main` recursively here.
Here's a modified version of your functions - therewith it should be easy to implement the  choice `5`:

```
void Data_Of_Branches(int number_of_branches, float arr_brms[number_of_branches][12])
{
  int i;
  int j;
  for (i = 0; i < number_of_branches; i++)
  {
    printf("Branch %d\n", i + 1);
    for (j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
      printf("Enter the data for the month %d: ", j + 1);
      scanf("%f", &arr_brms[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

void sum_of_sales(int number_of_branches, float arr_brms[number_of_branches][12])
{
  float sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < number_of_branches; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) sum += arr_brms[i][j];
  printf("The sum of all the branches income combined is = %f\n", sum);
}

int main()
{
  printf(
      "Please enter the number of branches you'd like to input data about: ");
  int number_of_branches = 0;
  scanf("%d", &number_of_branches);
  float arr_brms[number_of_branches][12];   // matrix for branches and months
  Data_Of_Branches(number_of_branches, arr_brms);
  printf("Hello. please enter the number of the operation you'd like to do. "
         "(please only enter the number.) \n \n");
  int choice;
  while (
    printf(" 1. Enter sales data.\n 2. Add a record for a new branch \n 3. "
           "Delete record of an existing branch \n 4. Calculate total sales \n "
           "5. Calculate percentage share of each branch \n 6. Determine the "
           "month of the peak sales \n 7. Display sales of a specific month \n "
           "8. Display sales of a specific branch \n 0. Done \n"),
    scanf("%d", &choice) > 0
        )
  {
    if (choice == 0) exit(0);
    if (choice == 1) Data_Of_Branches(number_of_branches, arr_brms);
    if (choice == 4) sum_of_sales(number_of_branches, arr_brms);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note that `Data_Of_Branches` is still vulnerable to ill-formed input.

> i went ahead and started -failing miserably at- adding the percentage function.

You mainly forgot to assign the return value of `sum_of_sales()` to `total_sale`. (By the way, it makes no sense to pass the uninitialized value of `total_sale` as a third argument to `sum_of_sales`.) But I wouldn't make it so, because this requires choice `4` before `5`. Instead I'd call `sum_of_sales()` within your `percentage` function, wherein you became confused by too much code (and needlessly replaced `12` by `m` while missing to initialize `m`) - if pruned, it works:

```
void percentage(int number_of_branches, float arr_brms[number_of_branches][12])
{
    int i, j, m = 12;
    float total = sum_of_sales(number_of_branches, arr_brms);
    for (i = 0; i < number_of_branches; i++)
    {
        printf("Branch %d: ", i+1);
        float per, sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) sum += arr_brms[i][j];
        per = sum / total * 100.0;
        printf("Percentage = %.2f%%\n", per);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me fix the code. i really appreciate it. with the way of how the variables are currently defined. all that i need is to just create new functions and have them call the ```float arr_brms[number_of_branches][12] , int number_of_branches``` at the beginning along with the  if i'm correct? like to create the new function to calculate the percentage of each branch i mean.

Comment: You are right, except that `int number_of_branches` must be the first parameter in order to be usable in `float arr_brms[number_of_branches][12]`.

Comment: if possible i'd like for you to check the question again as i have updated it.

Comment: it's giving me the error ``` too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have
      2``` in ``` float total = sum_of_sales(number_of_branches, arr_brms);
idk exactly the rules too well. but is there an easier way to contact you? like discord or something

Comment: I assumed that the useless third parameter `float total_sale` to `sum_of_sales` is removed, and I suggest you do so (in `main` as well as in the function definition).

Comment: Alright removed the third useless parameter, now the error is saying  ( error: initializing 'float' with an expression of incompatible type 'void' )

Comment: It seems you replaced your new version of `sum_of_sales` with my outdated version above (or you accidentally changed the function type from `float` back to `void`), but your version (with the `return total_sale;`) is fine when you only remove the third parameter `float total_sale` and of course prepend `float` to `total_sale = 0;`.

Comment: Many thanks that's what i was wrong at. i really appreciate you taking the time to actually reply to my questions it has really helped me a lot and showed me how friendly and patient the community is. thank you again will update the post now with the new code

Comment: You're welcome. - If you want to show a solution, you shouldn't put it in the question post, but rather make an answer of it.